# Encrypt data on reactjs and decrpt it in c# app

Tags: c#, reactjs

I have to encrypt some data on reactjs side and decrypt data in c# app.

I am trying rijndael-js in reactjs. And on c# side i am using RijndaelManaged. Own each one codes like below.

reactjs codes;

```
import Rijndael from "rijndael-js"

class ServiceRequester{
    getCrypto()
    {
        let original = "tolga";
        let key = "00000000000000000000000000000000"; // 32 length
        let iv = "0000000000000000"; // 16 length
        let cipher = new Rijndael(key, "cbc");
        let ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(original, 128, iv);

        console.log(ciphertext.toString("base64"));
        console.log(cipher.decrypt(ciphertext, 128, iv).toString());

        return ciphertext.toString("base64");
    }
}
```

c# code;

```cs
        public static string Decrypt(string encryptedText)
        {
            if (encryptedText == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var bytesToBeDecrypted = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);
            var bytesDecrypted = Decrypt(bytesToBeDecrypted);

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesDecrypted);
        }

        private static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] bytesToBeDecrypted)
        {
            byte[] decryptedBytes = null;

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var AES = new RijndaelManaged())
                {
                    AES.KeySize = 256;
                    AES.BlockSize = 128;
                    AES.Key = new byte[32];
                    AES.IV = new byte[16];
                    AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(bytesToBeDecrypted, 0, bytesToBeDecrypted.Length);
                        cs.Close();
                    }

                    decryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }

            return decryptedBytes;
        }
```

c# app been throwing an error. Error is

System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.

Comment: Hi all,

I found a solution. Solution is https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/encrypt-in-javascript-and-decrypt-in-C-Sharp-with-aes-algorithm-i/

I am using "crypto-js" over "rijndael-js" in reactjs any more. It worked for me!

Thanks to Saineshwar Bageri.

Comment: If it's answered, then you should add an answer and accept it yourself so the question is closed.